# Automatically restart a Service when the apk crashes

Tags: android

I want to restart my Service automatically if the application crashes. My ideas are:

1:
a BroadcastReceiver when the apk crashes and automatic restart the Service

```
if("android.intent.action.SOMETHING".equals(intent.getAction()))
  {
     Intent serviceLauncher = new Intent(context, Service.class);
     context.startService(serviceLauncher);
  }
```

2: 
with an uncaughtException(), but i dont know to handle that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you only need return START_STICKY in onStartCommand() of Service

Comment: i will try this as fast as i can and give you a report

Comment: i just read the description on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY and i think this is what i need, thank you

Comment: i think START_STICKY only make sure that the service starts but when service is running it does not restart him after a chrash, could it be?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY
It means your service will be re-started even it's running

Answer (score 2):

You can use
[setUncaughtExceptionHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29)

When receiving the event you can start the service again,

Another option, that might work (You need to try it), is calling StartService on the OnDestroy method.

Comment: Another option will not work as onDestroy won't be called.

Comment: setUncaughtExceptionHandler work's well. But (1) restart the service before kill the process and (2) if you don't want crash alert to be shown call `Process.killProcess(Process.myPid())` instead of `rootHandler.uncaughtException(thread, exception)`.

Comment: How to use `setUncaughtExceptionhandler` in such a scenario?

Answer (score -2):

Do you want your service to REALLY restart or you want your service to continue?
I think the service is not stopped when the application is crashed, a Service is separate of the application which create it.

Comment: hmm maybe my description is a little bit wrong, i want to restart the Service when it goes down.

Comment: I think the only solution is to isolate where your app will maybe crash(the crash of an app doesn't throw an action) and use a try-catch.